# Best practice in positioning sprites using SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, position, size

I am developing a simple game in Spritekit.

For the positioning the nodes as well as the sizes so that it looks good for both iPhone (iPhone X and older models) and iPads, I check if the device is iPhone and if it is iPhone, I will assign the posX and posY values for iPhone and if it is iPad, then I will assign the values which look good on iPad.

I do this for almost every single spritenode which are affected. In some spritenodes, I have to assign the width and height in addition to the X and Y positions.

So, as a result, there are lots of lines of code just to setup the spritenodes for the different devices.

Although this works it is tedious work.

I like to know what is the best practices for this. What do professional game developers companies do address such matters?

Thank you.

Comment: Just do it relative to the screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Sprite Kit is designed to be a 1 size fits all.  You should not have to worry about different screen sizes.

Take advantage of the cropping that is happening, and use a scene size that works in both iPad and IPhoneX (basically keep it 3:4, but large enough to accommodate X’s screen size.

If you find yourself absolutely needing to create different experiences across different aspect ratios, then try separating the projects as much as you can, and have them all call a common helper class.

If you want the same experience, then design your game with cropping in mind, and for things like your HUD (basically any static overlay) use UIKit so that it is not part of your SpriteKit update cycle.

Comment: Assuming, I want a button to appear at near the bottom of the scene.

Comment: Huh?  The button can go anywhere

Comment: Sorry - I did not mean to post that comment.